# Cross-server SQL query to read from one table (shared) and write to another (local)

Tags: sql-server, local, shared, cross-server

I've been having a very difficult time trying to read a table on one server and writing to another existing table on my hard drive (local... created using SQL Server Express).

Here's my code:

```
insert into [DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS].my_LOCAL_DATABASE.dbo.SHIPMENTS
select
    CUST_NUMBER,
    SHIPMENT_ID,
    SHIP_DATE,
    MODE_CODE,
    MILES,
    WEIGHT,
    AMOUNT_PAID
from SHARED_DATABASE.dbo.SHIPMENTS
where datepart(year,SHIP_DATE)= 2012 and datepart(month,SHIP_DATE) = 1
```

I get the following error message when I run this:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 7
>   Could not find server 'DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct
>   server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure
>   sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

So I've tried using

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver [DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS]
```

but I get this error:

> "Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSaddserver_internal, Line 29
>   User does not have permission to perform this action."

I'm a rookie SQL programmer, so I've had to research this extensively but with no success. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 'User does not have permission to perform this action" - You do not have sufficient permissions, simple as that.

Comment: FYI, cross-server queries can be [IMHO] extremely difficult to get to work consistantly. Its definitely an advanced subject, and one you should be wary of, at least so long as you consider yourself a rookie.

Answer (score 2):

`sp_addlinkedserver` execute permissions default to members of the sysadmin and setupadmin fixed server roles. Check out this [link](http://tweakingsqlserver.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/msg-15247-level-16-state-1-procedure.html) on how to sort it out on `sql server 2005`.

Once you get rid of that issue you could use the following to link and login to the other server.

```
--add the linked server and then login
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS',N'SQL Server';

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS', 
        @useself='false',
        @rmtuser='login_username',
        @rmtpassword='login_password'

--do your job here                    
Insert into [DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS].my_LOCAL_DATABASE.dbo.SHIPMENTS
Select...

--drop the linked server login and then drop the server
EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin 'DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS', NULL
EXEC sp_dropserver 'DPS-ABC1DE2\SQLEXPRESS', NULL;
```

Hope this helps...